# Converting Positive Logic to Negative logic. 7 Segment Decoder

Tags: digital-logic, negative

I was looking for a truth table for a seven segment decoder and saw that in order to display a three we must input a 0 for D, 0 for C, 1 for B and 1 for A. This will allow us to output the segments 1111001 which will display a 3. However if we wanted to convert this to binary logic would we just change the 0's to 1's and 1's to 0's?

Thanks for the help very new to this.

Comment: "Output the segments" doesn't actually mean anything until you put the segments in the circuit.

Comment: Also to convert to negative logic would we change and gates to nand gates? and Or gates to nor gates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is part of the truth table for a 7-segment decoder that would sink current for segments that are on (for example, to drive a common-anode LED display with open-drain or open-collector outputs). An example of that kind of decoder is the [SN7447](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn7447a.pdf). The output is '0' for a segment that is on.
[image]
[image]

If you were sourcing current (for example to drive a common-cathode LED display with emitter followers) then you'd want a '1' wherever the segment is on (the inverse of the above). An example of that kind of decoder is the [CD4511](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4511b.pdf).

[image]